# Scenekit low FPS and high memory usage issue

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, scenekit, frame-rate

I have created a 360-degree image viewer using `Scenekit`. In this viewer, I am simply creating a `sphere node` and attaching it to the `root node` of the `scene`. I am using high resolution captured images from `Aleta` camera for the texture of this sphere node.

I am not getting why scene kit is taking too much memory to show a 360-degree image. the size of my images is `12MB` and `resolution` is `11520 x 5760`. when I am loading the scene into the scene view my memory usage goes up to 400 MB which is a very horrible plus `FPS` drops drastically to `10-20 FPS`.

Following is my code for creating the scene:

```
 // Camera node and sphere node...

  var sphereNode : SCNNode!

  lazy var cameraNode: SCNNode = {
        let node = SCNNode()
        let camera = SCNCamera()
        node.camera = camera
        return node
    }()

// Material...

func getMaterial() -> SCNMaterial {
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.mipFilter = .nearest
    material.diffuse.magnificationFilter = .linear
    material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(-1, 1, 1)
    material.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
    material.cullMode = .front
    material.isDoubleSided = false
    return material
} 

// Setup scene...

func setup() {
    self.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 8)
    sphereNode = SCNNode()
    sphere.segmentCount = 300
    sphere.firstMaterial = getMaterial()
    sphereNode.geometry = sphere
    self.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
}
```

// Setting texture...

```
  room.getSceneTexture { (image) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.sceneView.updateMaterialTexture(image: image)
            }
        }
```

// Texture Method:

```
func getSceneTexture(completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
            guard let url = fileURL else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    completion(image)
                }
            }
            return completion(nil)
        }
```

After Capturing image from a camera I am setting material's content with the captured image.

Please let me know if anyone came across `scenekit's` memory issue.

Comment: To me nothing in the code you've shown could lead to such performance issues. There has to be something else. Can you share a minimal sample app that shows the issue?

Comment: @mnuages other than this code I have gestures on scene view which I am using to pan across the view to show 360 degree image.

Comment: @mnuages updated code for you.

Comment: @mnuages created sample app for you. You can see the memory usage go upto 400MB in it. FPS rate is good though. I don't know why this is happening. probably I am loading it from bundle that is why it's so fast.

Comment: @mnuages https://github.com/JarvisTheAvenger/360-degree-Image-Viewer